# How to get back the focus of already opened window in C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, api, focus

I have a windows application. When I click on a button another process starts which pops up the help window. I only want to open 1 window. So if I click on the button I am checking if the process is already started. The problem I am facing is how get the focus of the window that I opened.

```
if (processes.Length == 0)
{
      Process.Start();
}
else
{
  // Need to focus on the window already opened. 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a deleted post, Vinay reported that this also worked for him:

```
else
{
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        if (process.Id != p.Id)
        {
            SwitchToThisWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, true);
            return;
        }
    }

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method described by the [last Q&A at this link](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1757526), as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProcessWindows
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (p.Length > 0)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```